# How to specify Port Range in 'haproxy' frontend?

Tags: haproxy

I have haproxy working, but one port per line is specified.

```
frontend localhost
    bind *:8443
    bind *:443
    bind *:80
    bind *:8080
```

Say, if I want to specify port range, like `30000-35000`, how do I do that? I don't want to add 5K lines.

Comment: NM... I think I got solution. bind [<address>]:<port_range> [, ...]

Answer (score 2):

NM ... I got answer

```
bind [<address>]:<port_range> [, ...]
bind *:2000-2100
```

Particular care must be taken against port ranges, because every  couple consumes one socket (= a file descriptor), so it's easy to consume lots of descriptors with a simple range, and to run out of sockets